# Script for Copy files and paste that matched in directory and its subdirectories

Tags: linux, bash

I have 2 direcories

1. Modified
2. Updated

Modified directory contains:

```
loc.jpg
home.txt
first.p
```

Updated directory contains:

```
./updated/hyd/reg/loc.jpg
./updated/hyd/loc/home.txt
./updated/hyd/programs/first.p
```

How to copy modified files into matched files in updated directory

example:

`loc.jpg` should match `updated/hyd/reg/loc.jpg` and replace it

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

You can `for` loop over every file in your `modified` directory, executing `find` for each element and `cp` if a file is found:

**oneliner:**

```
for file in *; do find /path/to/updated -name "$file" -exec cp "$file" {} \; ; done
```

**script:**

```
for file in *
do
    find /path/to/updated -name "$file" -exec cp "$file" {} \;
done
```

**Explanation:**

- `for file in *` will loop over every file in your current directory, changing `$file` to the current filename
- `find /path/to/updated -name $file` will search for the given filename in your `updated` directory
- `-exec cp $file {} \;` will execute `cp` with `$file` and the output of `find` (`{}`) as arguments

**Example:**

```
╭─user@machine ~/test 
╰─$ cat updated/asdf 
╭─user@machine ~/test 
╰─$ cat asdf        
somecontent
╭─user@machine ~/test 
╰─$ for file in *; do find updated -name $file -exec cp $file {} \; ; done       

╭─user@machine ~/test 
╰─$ cat asdf
somecontent
╭─user@machine ~/test 
╰─$ cat updated/asdf 
somecontent
```